# How to create an Automator action to run sudo command

Tags: macos, sudo, automator

I am having trouble with creating an automator action, which runs the following sudo commands:

sudo kextunload -b com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport

sudo kextload -b com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport

for some reason i can't get it to work.

I would like for the automator action to promt me for my password

Thanks John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to edit your `/etc/sudoers` file, using `visudo` to add a line like this:

```
john    ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/kextunload, /sbin/kextload
```

after the lines that look like this:

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

That then says... allow user `john` to run `kextload` and `kextunload` on ALL machines without asking for a password.

**Note**: You can find your username (for the first word where I guessed `john`) by typing this into the Terminal:

```
id -unr
```

Comment: That still gives me the error message "You must be running as root to unload kexts, terminate services, or remove driver personalities."

Comment: Did you try `do shell script “sudo kextload ...kext” with administrator privileges`

Comment: I just tried: do shell script "sudo kextunload -b com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport" with administrator privileges    
That gives me the error "check the action's properies"

Answer (score 0):

Allright,

I managed to write a work around using this command instead: "/usr/bin/sudo launchctl stop com.apple.blued"

now it works like a charm (y)

Thanks